# Android draw circle around Text

Tags: android, textview

I have a textView with a single character in it (all single digit, numbers 0-9). I'd like to draw a circle or a square around the number. I saw a thread mention using a nine-patch to style around it, but I'm unsure of how to do this (or if it is the best way to do it). How can I have a circle around the number?

Thanks

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Just need to create a round drawable like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval">
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <stroke android:color="@color/red" android:width="2dip"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

And set this drawable as your TextView background.

Comment: Why do you use coners inside oval shape? From documentation:<corners> Creates rounded corners for the shape. Applies only when the shape is a rectangle.

Comment: This draws oval instead of circle

Comment: add padding left and right slightly more than top and bottom to textView

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke android:color="@color/teal_200" android:width="2dip"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <size
        android:width="10dp"
        android:height="10dp" 
    />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just give that TextView a Shape drawable that is a circle as a background.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape