# Draw text inside a circle

Tags: android, drawable

I'm working on an Android application and I want to draw a circle with text inside. I want the fill to be white with a black boarder and black text. Right now I have a `ShapeDrawable`:

```
mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xFFFFFF);
```

This however makes the whole circle white (and with a white background you can't see it) and after a while searching as to how you can add text to the shape I can't seem to find an answer that works. I should also note that I will be adding an arbitrary number of circles with different text in each based on user input. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Drawable is not used to draw text, you should try bitmap, just like Geralt illustrated

Comment: what??? Drawable is used to draw everything that can be drawn using a Canvas

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060470/android-draw-circle-around-text

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try this alternative method.

Create a drawable file oval.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
   <solid android:color="#fff"/>
   <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#000"/>
</shape>
```

Then create a RelativeLayout and set the background with the oval drawable

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/circle"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/oval" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The result will be something like this:

[image]

Comment: I edited my question to add in a key piece of information in that I will need multiple circles with different text in each. This will have to be done programmably so I can not simple hard code them into the xml files

Comment: This answer is great because in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060470/android-draw-circle-around-text you are told to set the oval drawable as background for the TextView. But if you don't draw a filled circle then TextView touches the edges of the circle. So the method with a RelativeLayout surrounding the TextView is far better!

Comment: If you don't need to use an outline around your background DON't use the RelativeLayout as a container for the TextView. In most cases this is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

I am sure late to reply here, but this might be helpful to others.

```
    ShapeDrawable colorCode = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
    colorCode.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL); //See more paint style for border circle etc. like STROKE
    colorCode.getPaint().setAntiAlias(true);
    colorCode.getPaint().setColor(getResources().getColor(YOUR_COLOUR_HERE_FROM_XML));
    colorCode.setIntrinsicHeight(Globals.dp2px(5, getActivity())); //converting dp to px, you can just put any integer instead of dp2px method
    colorCode.setIntrinsicWidth(Globals.dp2px(5, getActivity()));
    greenText.setBackgroundDrawable(colorCode);
```

Comment: `setBackgroundDrawable` is now deprecated, but just replace with `setBackground`