# Android : Draw Circle With Text Inside

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-view

I need to draw three circles in my fragment ,the circles differ in size, I refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20168311/1450401) 
The result i obtained is this

[image]

This is my XML Code : UPDATED

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/large_volume"
             android:layout_width="185dp"
             android:layout_height="185dp"
             android:background="@drawable/circle"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="My name is NON"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
             android:textSize="10dp" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/medium_volume"
             android:layout_width="120dp"
             android:layout_height="120dp"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/large_volume"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/large_volume"
             android:background="@drawable/circle"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="My name is NON"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
             android:textSize="10dp" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/TextView02"
             android:layout_width="90dp"
             android:layout_height="90dp"
             android:layout_below="@+id/medium_volume"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/large_volume"
             android:background="@drawable/circle"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="-17dp"
             android:text="My name is NON"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
             android:textSize="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

But what i need must be is like this [image]

You can see the circles must stay close together , But when i use XML view i can't achieve this . How can i achieve this , I need `onClickListeners` in my circle thats why i use views

Is this can achieve through Canvas drawing , i heard canvas is not  view so this will restrict me from giving click listeners ,Correct me if i am wrong

**UPDATE :**

I fulfill my need through XML approach ,is there any way to achieve this through canvas drawing ,Should i post  another question for that ??

Comment: You can try add padding in -ve value to the views

Comment: @RDC thanks you instead of -ive padding i give negative value for margins, that help me to achieve what i needed

Comment: @edwin did one of these answers work for you? Please accept! Thanks!

Comment: @Rachael My question was to achieve it through Programmatically using canvas. But none of the answer point out that

Answer (score 41):

Try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/num_txt"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_red"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="My name is NON"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Save in drawable `bg_red.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:shape="oval">
        <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
        <stroke android:color="#FF0000" android:width="5dip"/>
        <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
    </shape>
```

---

Edited Code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/num_txt"
             android:layout_width="185dp"
             android:layout_height="185dp"

             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_marginTop="163dp"
             android:background="@drawable/bg_red"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="My name is NON"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
             android:textSize="10dp" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/TextView02"
             android:layout_width="90dp"
             android:layout_height="90dp"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/TextView01"
             android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="122dp"
             android:background="@drawable/bg_red"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="My name is NON"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
             android:textSize="10dp" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/TextView01"
             android:layout_width="120dp"
             android:layout_height="120dp"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/num_txt"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/num_txt"
             android:background="@drawable/bg_red"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="My name is NON"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
             android:textSize="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**ConstraintLayout use for badge count.**

[image]

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tab_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab_badge"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_badge"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:text="10"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tab_icon"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tab_icon" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: thanks, for removing additional layouts, But it still look same as the image i post, i will update my xml code

Comment: You can See The small circle must stay close to large circle

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CircularTextView extends TextView
{
private float strokeWidth;
int strokeColor,solidColor;

public CircularTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CircularTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CircularTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}


@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

    Paint circlePaint = new Paint();
    circlePaint.setColor(solidColor);
    circlePaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    Paint strokePaint = new Paint();
    strokePaint.setColor(strokeColor);
    strokePaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    int  h = this.getHeight();
    int  w = this.getWidth();

    int diameter = ((h > w) ? h : w);
    int radius = diameter/2;

    this.setHeight(diameter);
    this.setWidth(diameter);

    canvas.drawCircle(diameter / 2 , diameter / 2, radius, strokePaint);

    canvas.drawCircle(diameter / 2, diameter / 2, radius-strokeWidth, circlePaint);

    super.draw(canvas);
}

public void setStrokeWidth(int dp)
{
    float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    strokeWidth = dp*scale;

}

public void setStrokeColor(String color)
{
    strokeColor = Color.parseColor(color);
}

public void setSolidColor(String color)
{
    solidColor = Color.parseColor(color);

}
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34685568/2809351

Answer (score 1):

if you wish change in runtime the saved background..

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
if (something) {
  textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_red);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="83dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="185dp"
        android:layout_height="185dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="113dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

you can set directly backroud or drawable to the textview.
you can use drawablepadding ,etc.....

or you can use:
 **android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_cab_done_holo_dark"**

Comment: i am not setting any drawable in my textview, so why should i use drawablepadding ?? how it will help me ??

Comment: For this you need to created custom view, and in that onDraw() method you can draw circles with background and text.

Comment: @DeepchandSingh i achieve my need through XML, can you show how can it achieve through onDraw method

Comment: @edwin Great if you achieved through XML.
If you want to give it a try using canvas, 
just have a look at: http://v2beastzbroz.blogspot.in/2013/06/tutorial-for-canvas-drawing-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
    gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
    gd.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    gd.setStroke(5, Color.BLUE);
    gd.setSize(getTextViewHeight(tv),getTextViewHeight(tv));

    tv.setBackground(gd);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
            gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
            gd.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            gd.setStroke(5, Color.BLUE);
            gd.setSize(tv.getHeight(),tv.getHeight());
            Log.d("DB121","Width "+tv.getHeight()+ "Height ="+tv.getHeight());
            tv.setBackground(gd);
        }
    });
}
public static int getTextViewHeight(TextView textView) {
    WindowManager wm =
            (WindowManager) textView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    int deviceWidth;

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2){
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        deviceWidth = size.x;
    } else {
        deviceWidth = display.getWidth();
    }

    int widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(deviceWidth, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    int heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    textView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    return textView.getMeasuredHeight();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to create dynamically circle with textview

```
RelativeLayout main_rel_layout = findViewById(R.id.main_rel_layout);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
textView.setText("Hello ");
textView.setTextSize(100);
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = new FloatingActionButton(this);
floatingActionButton.setCustomSize(400);
frameLayout.addView(floatingActionButton);

relativeLayout.addView(frameLayout);
relativeLayout.addView(textView);
main_rel_layout.addView(relativeLayout);
```