# Changing a color resource programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I got a little circle TextView from Vicky Vicent ("[Android: Creating a Circular TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203501/android-creating-a-circular-textview/25203778)")
In my situation this one should show a Level and I would like to define the background color for certain areas by myself. How can I change this one with my Activity?

```
<solid android:color="#9FE554" />
```

Comment: You can't edit resource files at run-time

Answer (score 1):

To change the solid color of the xml drawable resource use the below code.

```
GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable)textview.getBackground();
bgShape.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```