# How to add icon image button in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

[image]

I want to design the layout of this type of app(as shown in the image). In this layout when we click the circle icon it moves to next page. I want to know how its done.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2xLu1.jpg

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178193/android-draw-circle-with-text-inside

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in drawer folder create circle_background.xml and put this code to it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#FE4543"></solid>
     <stroke android:color="#FE4543" android:width="1dp"></stroke>

</shape>
```

so now in your activity add image view like this

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_search"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
        />
```

and if you want to add click action on this you have to use intent something like this , my view id is btn_search so at the first i have to  find it like this and then set onclick listener for it like below

```
 ImageView btnSearch= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ExampleActivity.class)
                
            }
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The top one I think it can implement by `ImageButton` simplely.

Another one need a `Layout` with a circle background, and contain `ImageView` and `TextView`.

Hope it will be help for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class TourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView tour;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tour);

        tour = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tour);
        tour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FirstActivity.class);
                    launchThird();
            }
        });
    }

    private void launchThird() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to provide more to your answer than just code. Consider explaining what was wrong, or how you are fixing the original problem