# Draw Arc around a textview like a progressBar

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-canvas

I want to draw an arc around my textview , but I'm struggling to do it.

I'm trying to draw an Arc with canvas, transforming it on a drawable and then apply to the background of the textview. The thing is the arc isn't showing...
Here is the code to create the drawable :

```
 Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    RectF rectF = new RectF(100,100,100,200);
    c.drawArc(rectF, 0 , 180, true, new Paint(Color.BLACK));
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(b);
```

I have this(1st screenshot)  and I want to do this(2nd),

[image: What]

[image: What I Want]

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom circle `drawable` and then assign it to background of `TextView`.

Create custom drawable like below:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#00ff00"/>
</shape>
```

For more circular drawables options, Please [view this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185103/how-to-define-a-circle-shape-in-an-android-xml-drawable-file)

Comment: The thing is I can work with that but i was trying to use a canvas. Drawing an arc but then the arc didn't appear... I need an arc like a progress view that's why im asking this...

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38657335/draw-a-text-on-a-circle-path-in-android and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224384/draw-text-inside-android-circle ,this might help