# circle or a square around the number in android with special characters

Tags: android, special-characters

is there any way to create a circle or a square around the number in android  with  special characters like this: ➊, but with own number?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060470/android-draw-circle-around-text

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178193/android-draw-circle-with-text-inside

Comment: do you got it done

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya this won't help me. i want to have something like whatsapp badger in tablayout .text+ (number of new message in circle)

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i want to draw circlee around just part of text not all of it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292838/android-spannablestring-set-background-behind-part-of-text

Answer (score 0):

Yes. use android view badger.
https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger
of course you have second way to make it.
1. create your own xml shape file for oval shape.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

   <solid 
       android:color="#666666"/>

   <size 
       android:width="120dp"
       android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

2. use a textview and set this drawable to background of textview
3. set every number that you want to as text to textview

Comment: thank ,but i want to use special characters not shape or other way

Answer (score 0):

> for special character you can use UniCodes or some custom fonts.

```
<TextView
    width...
    height...
    android:background="@drawable/createShapeInDrawableFolder"/>
```

As answered by **Mohammad moradyar**